# Prove that closed form is zero somewhere on the unit sphere.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

If $\sigma$ is an arbitrary closed differential 2-form on the unit ball $\mathbb{B}^3=\{(x, y, z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1\}$, prove that there exists a point $p$ on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2=\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2+z^2 =1\}$ where $\sigma (p)=0$ ($0$, the multilinear zero-mapping).

I'm trying to solve this using Stokes' theorem, because if $\sigma$ is closed, $d\sigma=0$, so $\iiint_{\mathbb{B}^3}d\sigma=\iint_{\mathbb{S}^2}\sigma=0$, and then if $\sigma = Pdy \wedge dz+Qdz\wedge dx+Rdx\wedge dy$, maybe use the continuity of $P, Q, R$ to prove that they have to be $0$ somewhere. The problem I'm facing is, I'm not sure if there has to exist a point where they're all simultaneously $0$.

Comment: You're having a conceptual problem here. To say that $\sigma$ vanishes — as a $2$-form on the sphere — at some point does *not* mean that $P=Q=R=0$ at that point. We're not talking about the $2$-form on $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the unit sphere the form restricts to a scalar function $\phi$ times
$$\omega=x\,dy\wedge dz+y\,dz\wedge dx+z\,dx\wedge dy.$$
This corresponds to the "outward normal". Integrating $\sigma=\phi\omega$
over $S^2$ just corresponds to integrating the scalar $\phi$ with respect
to surface area on the sphere. If this integral is zero, then $\phi$
must be zero somewhere.

Comment: Could you explain why $\sigma=\phi \omega$ on the unit sphere? I'm only able to see $\sigma$ as $P dy \wedge dz + Q dz \wedge dx + R dx \wedge dy$, so $\frac{P}{x}=\frac{Q}{y}=\frac{R}{z}=\phi$ would have to hold.

Comment: The reason is that any $2$-form on the $2$-sphere is some scalar function times the area $2$-form (which gives a basis for the $1$-dimensional vector space $\bigwedge^2 T^*_xS^2$ for each point $x\in S^2$).

Comment: Oh, I see. Because $\mathbb{S}^2$ is a 2-dimensional manifold, the space $\Omega^2(\mathbb{S}^2)$ is 1-dimensional, so any of its nontrivial elements spans it?

Comment: Careful, @MatijaSreckovic. $\Omega^2(S^2)$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space, but it's one-dimensional as a module over the ring of smooth functions.